# Run-time error on 'Copy' Method

Tags: excel, runtime-error, vba

I am getting a run-time error on a copy method.

The error message is:

> *"Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)': Method 'Copy' of object 'Range' failed"*

The error is pointing to below line of code:

> *WST.Cells.Copy Destination:=WSD.Cells(1, 1)*

Here is all the vba in the workbook.

```
Option Explicit
Sub CreateReport()
Dim WSD As Worksheet
Dim WST As Worksheet
Dim ST As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastRow1 As Long
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim FinalRow As Long
Dim i As Long


ST = 7
Set WSD = ActiveSheet
FinalRow = 42
Set WST = Sheets("BIF BR Prospects-Per Mgmt")
LastRow = WST.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
If LastRow > 1 Then
 WST.Cells(2, 1).Resize(LastRow - 1, 13).Copy
 WSD.Cells(FinalRow, 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown

 WSD.Cells(FinalRow, 13).Resize(LastRow - 1, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-8]& ""/"" & RC[-2]"
 WSD.Cells(FinalRow, 5).Resize(LastRow - 1, 1).Value = WSD.Cells(FinalRow, 13).Resize(LastRow - 1, 1).Value
 WSD.Cells(FinalRow, 11).Resize(LastRow - 1, 1).ClearContents
 WSD.Cells(FinalRow, 13).Resize(LastRow - 1, 1).ClearContents

 WSD.Cells(FinalRow, 14).Resize(LastRow - 1, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(OR(RC[-5]="""",RC[-2]=""""),"""",RC[-5] & "" "" & RC[-2])"
 WSD.Cells(FinalRow, 9).Resize(LastRow - 1, 1).Value = WSD.Cells(FinalRow, 14).Resize(LastRow - 1, 1).Value
 WSD.Cells(FinalRow, 12).Resize(LastRow - 1, 1).ClearContents
 WSD.Cells(FinalRow, 14).Resize(LastRow - 1, 1).ClearContents


 WSD.Rows(FinalRow + LastRow - 1).Copy
 WSD.Rows(FinalRow & ":" & FinalRow + LastRow - 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

 WSD.Cells(FinalRow + LastRow, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTA(R[" & -LastRow & "]C[-1]:R[-2]C[-1])"
 WSD.Cells(FinalRow + LastRow, 5).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[" & -LastRow & "]C[5]:R[-2]C[5])"
 WSD.Rows(FinalRow + LastRow - 1).Delete

 WSD.Range(Cells(FinalRow - 1, 1), Cells(FinalRow + LastRow - 2, 10)).Select
 WSD.Sort.SortFields.Clear
 WSD.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range(Cells(FinalRow, 6), Cells(FinalRow + LastRow - 2, 6)), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
 WSD.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range(Cells(FinalRow, 4), Cells(FinalRow + LastRow - 2, 4)), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
 With WSD.Sort
    .SetRange Range(Cells(FinalRow - 1, 1), Cells(FinalRow + LastRow - 2, 10))
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .Apply
 End With

End If

FinalRow = FinalRow - ST
Set WST = Sheets("Funnel Status-Per AE info")
LastRow = WST.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = WST.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 2
If LastRow > 1 Then
 Range(WST.Cells(1, 1), WST.Cells(LastRow, 1)).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range(WST.Cells(1, LastCol), WST.Cells(1, LastCol)), Unique:=True
 LastRow1 = WST.Cells(Rows.Count, LastCol).End(xlUp).Row
 WST.Cells(1, LastCol + 1) = 1
 WST.Cells(1, LastCol + 2) = 2
 WST.Cells(1, LastCol + 3) = 3
 WST.Cells(1, LastCol + 4) = 4
 WST.Cells(1, LastCol + 5) = 5

 WST.Cells(2, LastCol + 1).Resize(LastRow1 - 1, 5).FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIFS(C1,RC4,C2,R1C)"
 WST.Cells(2, LastCol + 1).Resize(LastRow1 - 1, 5).Value = WST.Cells(2, LastCol + 1).Resize(LastRow1 - 1, 5).Value
 WST.Cells(2, LastCol).Resize(LastRow1 - 1, 11).Copy
 WSD.Cells(FinalRow, 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown

 WSD.Rows(FinalRow + LastRow1 - 1).Copy
 WSD.Rows(FinalRow & ":" & FinalRow + LastRow1 - 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

 Range(WST.Cells(1, LastCol), WST.Cells(LastRow1, LastCol + 5)).ClearContents
 WSD.Cells(FinalRow, 7).Resize(LastRow1 + 1, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-5]:RC[-1])"
 WSD.Cells(FinalRow + LastRow1 - 1, 7) = ""
 WSD.Cells(FinalRow + LastRow1, 2).Resize(1, 5).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[" & -LastRow1 & "]C:R[-2]C)"
 WSD.Rows(FinalRow + LastRow1 - 1).Delete
End If

FinalRow = FinalRow - ST
Set WST = Sheets("BR Opened this week")
LastRow = WST.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
If LastRow > 1 Then
 WST.Cells(2, 1).Resize(LastRow - 1, 12).Copy
 WSD.Cells(FinalRow, 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown

 WSD.Cells(FinalRow, 12).Resize(LastRow - 1, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-7]& ""/"" & RC[-2]"
 WSD.Cells(FinalRow, 5).Resize(LastRow - 1, 1).Value = WSD.Cells(FinalRow, 12).Resize(LastRow - 1, 1).Value
 WSD.Cells(FinalRow, 10).Resize(LastRow - 1, 1).ClearContents
 WSD.Cells(FinalRow, 12).Resize(LastRow - 1, 1).ClearContents

 WSD.Cells(FinalRow, 13).Resize(LastRow - 1, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(OR(RC[-6]="""",RC[-2]=""""),"""",RC[-6] & "" "" & RC[-2])"
 WSD.Cells(FinalRow, 7).Resize(LastRow - 1, 1).Value = WSD.Cells(FinalRow, 13).Resize(LastRow - 1, 1).Value
 WSD.Cells(FinalRow, 11).Resize(LastRow - 1, 1).ClearContents
 WSD.Cells(FinalRow, 13).Resize(LastRow - 1, 1).ClearContents



 WSD.Rows(FinalRow + LastRow - 1).Copy
 WSD.Rows(FinalRow & ":" & FinalRow + LastRow - 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

 WSD.Cells(FinalRow + LastRow, 4).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[" & -LastRow & "]C[5]:R[-2]C[5])"
 WSD.Rows(FinalRow + LastRow - 1).Delete
End If

FinalRow = FinalRow - ST
Set WST = Sheets("REMOVED from BIF this week")
LastRow = WST.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
If LastRow > 1 Then
 WST.Cells(2, 1).Resize(LastRow - 1, 11).Copy
 WSD.Cells(FinalRow, 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown

 WSD.Cells(FinalRow, 13).Resize(LastRow - 1, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-8]& ""/"" & RC[-2]"
 WSD.Cells(FinalRow, 5).Resize(LastRow - 1, 1).Value = WSD.Cells(FinalRow, 13).Resize(LastRow - 1, 1).Value
 WSD.Cells(FinalRow, 11).Resize(LastRow - 1, 1).ClearContents
 WSD.Cells(FinalRow, 13).Resize(LastRow - 1, 1).ClearContents


 WSD.Rows(FinalRow + LastRow - 1).Copy
 WSD.Rows(FinalRow & ":" & FinalRow + LastRow - 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

 WSD.Cells(FinalRow + LastRow, 4).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[" & -LastRow & "]C[6]:R[-2]C[6])"
 WSD.Rows(FinalRow + LastRow - 1).Delete
End If

FinalRow = FinalRow - ST
Set WST = Sheets("BR Backlog of conf-unopened")
LastRow = WST.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
If LastRow > 1 Then
 WST.Cells(2, 1).Resize(LastRow - 1, 12).Copy
 WSD.Cells(FinalRow, 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown

 WSD.Cells(FinalRow, 12).Resize(LastRow - 1, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-7]& ""/"" & RC[-2]"
 WSD.Cells(FinalRow, 5).Resize(LastRow - 1, 1).Value = WSD.Cells(FinalRow, 12).Resize(LastRow - 1, 1).Value
 WSD.Cells(FinalRow, 10).Resize(LastRow - 1, 1).ClearContents
 WSD.Cells(FinalRow, 12).Resize(LastRow - 1, 1).ClearContents

 WSD.Cells(FinalRow, 13).Resize(LastRow - 1, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(OR(RC[-6]="""",RC[-2]=""""),"""",RC[-6] & "" "" & RC[-2])"
 WSD.Cells(FinalRow, 7).Resize(LastRow - 1, 1).Value = WSD.Cells(FinalRow, 13).Resize(LastRow - 1, 1).Value
 WSD.Cells(FinalRow, 11).Resize(LastRow - 1, 1).ClearContents
 WSD.Cells(FinalRow, 13).Resize(LastRow - 1, 1).ClearContents




 WSD.Rows(FinalRow + LastRow - 1).Copy
 WSD.Rows(FinalRow & ":" & FinalRow + LastRow - 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

 WSD.Cells(FinalRow + LastRow, 4).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[" & -LastRow & "]C[5]:R[-2]C[5])"
 WSD.Rows(FinalRow + LastRow - 1).Delete
End If

FinalRow = FinalRow - ST
Set WST = Sheets("BR Set-Confirmed this week")
LastRow = WST.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
If LastRow > 1 Then
 WST.Cells(2, 1).Resize(LastRow - 1, 12).Copy
 WSD.Cells(FinalRow, 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown

 WSD.Cells(FinalRow, 12).Resize(LastRow - 1, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-7]& ""/"" & RC[-2]"
 WSD.Cells(FinalRow, 5).Resize(LastRow - 1, 1).Value = WSD.Cells(FinalRow, 12).Resize(LastRow - 1, 1).Value
 WSD.Cells(FinalRow, 10).Resize(LastRow - 1, 1).ClearContents
 WSD.Cells(FinalRow, 12).Resize(LastRow - 1, 1).ClearContents

 WSD.Cells(FinalRow, 13).Resize(LastRow - 1, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(OR(RC[-6]="""",RC[-2]=""""),"""",RC[-6] & "" "" & RC[-2])"
 WSD.Cells(FinalRow, 7).Resize(LastRow - 1, 1).Value = WSD.Cells(FinalRow, 13).Resize(LastRow - 1, 1).Value
 WSD.Cells(FinalRow, 11).Resize(LastRow - 1, 1).ClearContents
 WSD.Cells(FinalRow, 13).Resize(LastRow - 1, 1).ClearContents

 WSD.Rows(FinalRow + LastRow - 1).Copy
 WSD.Rows(FinalRow & ":" & FinalRow + LastRow - 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

 WSD.Cells(FinalRow + LastRow, 4).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[" & -LastRow & "]C[5]:R[-2]C[5])"
 WSD.Rows(FinalRow + LastRow - 1).Delete

End If
Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit
WSD.Range(Columns(11).Address & ":" & Columns(Columns.Count).Address).ClearContents
WSD.Cells(1, 1).Select

End Sub
Sub ClearReport()

 Dim WSD As Worksheet
 Dim WST As Worksheet
 Set WSD = ActiveSheet
 Set WST = Sheets("GM")
 WST.Cells.Copy Destination:=WSD.Cells(1, 1)
End Sub
Sub Printing()

    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
      .Orientation = xlLandscape
      .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
      .Zoom = False
      .FitToPagesWide = 1
      .FitToPagesTall = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Works fine for me. What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Version 14.0.7143.  I forgot to mention that the error started after a windows update.  Looks like it was caused by a security update to Excel (kb2956081).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem with your code and a Google search shows a variety of different information/circumstances where this error pops up. From [the Windows Wiki page](http://winwiki.org/excel-run-time-error-80010108/):

"Excel Run Time Error 80010108 Error Codes are caused in one way or another by misconfigured system files in your windows operating system."

Which would explain why it works for others when they try the same code. There is a fix utility listed on that site.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue, for me due to Excel update KB2956081. Issue is not in Macro but in Excel with copy/past action. If a whole sheet (all cells are selected) is copied and past to an other sheet. (or past special), so Excel is crashing. (But Dos no crash if selection is not all cells). A macro including a such command make generates an automation error.
If update is removed Excel go right again.

Comment: Hi, this is not an answer. Please use the comments field if you have something to add to a question.